# How to change the text depending upon the value getting from data base?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the distance by location and location is stored is in firebase data base, here I want to change the text if the distance is O between two points.(Like less than km not the value "O").Pls help me out..

I tried doing this but not working, to give you some idea here is the code:-

```
 setState(() {
        if(value?.distanceBW != null){
          distanceBW = value.distanceBW;
          if(distanceBW == 0 ){
            setState(() {
              return "Less than 1";
            });

          }else{
            return distanceBW;
          }

        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a top level variable, say `String textToDisplay = "";`
Then update it's value accordingly like:

```dart
if(value?.distanceBW != null){
    distanceBW = value.distanceBW;
    if(distanceBW == "0" || distanceBW.isEmpty())
      setState(() => textToDisplay = "Less than 1");
    else
      setState(() => textToDisplay = distanceBW.toString()); 
}
```

Use this variable `textToDisplay` in your `Text` widget,
also make sure to give a type `String` to `distanceBW` instead of `var`.

Comment: Please add that stacktrace as well

Comment: there is no such error, but the value where I am displaying there it is displaying null.

Comment: and in (distanceBW == 0 ) it says:- Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types.

Comment: then most probably your `distanceBW` is of String or some other type. according to that, check in the if block

Comment: distanceBW is var

Comment: Yeah but the value it holds must be having a type, what is the type of `value.distanceBW`?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: still no difference. Now just null has been removed and nothing else is displaying.